# Identical lines of code that work on Python Shell don't work when used as a function body

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

We have the following code that works:

```
for item in feed.entries:
        print(item["summary"], item["title"],item["published"])
        enclosures = [l for l in item["links"] if l["rel"] == "enclosure"]
        if (len(enclosures)>0):
            enclosure = enclosures[0]
            sourceurl = enclosure["href"]
            cik = item["edgar_ciknumber"]
            targetfname = df.target_dir+cik+'-'+sourceurl.split('/')[-1]
            retry_counter = 3
            while retry_counter >0:
                good_read = downloadfile(sourceurl, targetfname)
                if good_read:
                    break
                else:
                    print("Retrying:", retry_counter)
                    retry_counter -=1
```

If i type this code in the Python Shell the code retrieves `String` data about `ZIP` files (summary, title etc.), outputs them and finally it lets us know it downloaded the `ZIP` file:

```
1.Retrieves and outputs String data about Zip files
10-Q FIRST SOLAR, INC. (0001274494) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:42:54 EDT

2.Notifies us it downloaded the file:
Downloading: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1274494/000127449410000029/0001274494-10-000029-xbrl.zip
```

---

**The problem is** that if i put this code block as a body to a function **it only retrieves String data about the ZIP files and does NOT download the ZIP files!**

So instead of getting:

```
10-Q FIRST SOLAR, INC. (0001274494) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:42:54 EDT
Downloading: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1274494/000127449410000029/0001274494-10-000029-xbrl.zip
10-Q CARTERS INC (0001060822) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:19:14 EDT
Downloading: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1060822/000106082210000034/0001060822-10-000034-xbrl.zip
10-Q VISA INC. (0001403161) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:14:09 EDT
Downloading: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1403161/000119312510172477/0001193125-10-172477-xbrl.zip
10-Q/A DELTA AIR LINES INC /DE/ (0000027904) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 18:49:34 EDT
Downloading: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/27904/000095012310070614/0000950123-10-070614-xbrl.zip
```

I am getting:

```
10-Q FIRST SOLAR, INC. (0001274494) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:42:54 EDT
10-Q CARTERS INC (0001060822) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:19:14 EDT
10-Q VISA INC. (0001403161) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 19:14:09 EDT
10-Q/A DELTA AIR LINES INC /DE/ (0000027904) (Filer) Fri, 30 Jul 2010 18:49:34 EDT
```

....and of course the **ZIP files are not downloaded.**

- How is this possible when it is the exact same lines of code on both cases?

---

**PS:** I have re-written the module in case there was an error in indentation.

**PS2:** I have deleted all files that should be downloaded in order to eliminate the possibility of existing local copies that are identical and conflict with the downloaded ones.

**PS3:** Function `downloadfile` is imported on every testing.

**EDIT**

Does the problem surface when the code snippet above is part of a function block from within the shell? or when it's part of a function block within a script file? Can you post an example of a script that fails for you? by [jkyako](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3479699/jkyako)

If i put the code block within a function body and *define* it into the shell it runs smoothly. Thank you. When i try to `import` the function from the module i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    contie(g)
  File "E:\Py_env\df2.py", line 11, in contie
    targetfname = df.target_dir+cik +' - ' +sourceurl.split('/')[-1] #df.target_dir change made
NameError: global name 'df' is not defined
```

`df` is the name of the module that contains the function.

Comment: Please read ["The evils of `except`"](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/).

Comment: Perhaps you should finish reading it first, but long story short: `try: len(try_block) == minimum_possible; except SpecificError: do_something_useful()`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have decided to remove the `try/except` since it is a small piece of code and i want to know any error that pops up. However on this scenario only USE_1 is taking place.

Comment: Does the problem surface when the code snippet above is part of a function block from within the shell?  or when it's part of a function block within a script file?  Can you post an example of a script that fails for you?

Comment: @jkyako posting an edit right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a function with the code block and place it in the `df` module, you should be able to reference `df.target_dir` simply as `target_dir` since both the function and `target_dir` are in the same module/namespace:

```
def f():
    # ...
    targetfname = target_dir+cik+'-'+sourceurl.split('/')[-1]
    # ...
```

If you want to define it in a function in a separate module, (eg `E:\Py_env\df2.py` from your trace above), you'll need to import the `df` module and then you can reference `df.target_dir` in the function.  ie:

```
import df
# ...
def f():
    # ...
    targetfname = df.target_dir+cik+'-'+sourceurl.split('/')[-1]
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea here is that this code is very difficult to debug because there is so much code inside the `try` block, so if something gets thrown to `except` you have no idea what it is. Try something like:

```
for thing in stuff:
    ...
    ...
    try: 
       # here is the one bit that you expect to fail for a specific reason
    except: 
        raise Exception("cik number not found for item %s" % item) # for example
        continue # skip the subsequent lines and step into the next iteration of the loop
```

Besides that, it's hard to say why this did one thing in the shell and another when imported. That is perplexing, and my instinct is to say that something was slightly different but went unnoticed.

Comment: Yes but when the code is typed in the Shell it runs smoothly and downloads the files... how can i make it to show any error?

Comment: Maybe i should totally omit `try:` and `except:`

Comment: just rerun the function from within your module, but remove the `try/except` statements. then you'll see what's causing the error, no? EDIT: exactly, just saw your response.